# Is any one aware of windows event to trap the mouse and keyboard input

Tags: windows, input, events, trace

I want to trap windows mouse and keyboard input with the help of event given by windows for detecting system idle or not in C++.

Two things I have tried:
1. Hooking concept, but as antivirus might not allow it and also CPU usage increases if we use hooking.
2. GetLastInputInfo() which also eats CPU usage about 50 %

Anyone can tell me if windows event to trap the mouse and keyboard input is available or not...

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to do any better than [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) and WH_KEYBOARD & WH_MOUSE.  The documentation for [MouseProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988(VS.85).aspx) & [KeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644984(VS.85).aspx) will be handy as well.